# Understanding a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

By definition, we have that:

$\mathbb{Q}[x,y] = (\mathbb{Q}[x])[y] = (\mathbb{Q}[y])[x]$.

Now I want to come to the conclusion that: $(\mathbb{Q}[y])[x]/(x) \cong \mathbb{Q}[y]$.

I'm not sure how to go about

Comment: Note that as you've framed the desired "conclusion", it is a special case of the more general isomorphism $R[x]/(x) \cong R$ for arbitrary ring $R$, setting $R = \mathbb Q[y]$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $R:=\Bbb Q[y]$, and determine the kernel of the homomorphism $R[x]\to R$ sending $x\mapsto0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You can define the homomorphism as

\begin{align}
      \mathbf Q[y][x]&\longrightarrow\mathbf Q[y]\\
                P(x,y)&\longmapsto P(0,y)
\end{align}

Comment: But how would I come to the conclusion that $(\mathbb{Q}[y])[x]/(x) \cong \mathbb{Q}[y]?$

Comment: What do you think the kernel is?